# VSCode php-debug won't stop on breakpoints until I've stopped at a xdebug_break()

Tags: php, debugging, visual-studio-code

The issue is rather curious. So I'm using VSCode and the php-debug extension, have configured XDebug and the (remote) connection works ok. However, none of my breakpoints will be hit *until* I've

1. Stopped at a `xdebug_break()`
2. Hit F9 twice, to add and remove a breakpoint at the line I was stopped at
3. Continue with F5 - now all breakpoints work fine

So I'm at a loss on how to proceed. I can obviously still use this, but it is a bit silly having to go through that every time I start debugging (and finding out that the double-tap F9 actually worked wasn't all that easy :)